# Google Or-tools on python with own meta-heuristic

Tags: or-tools

I would like to solve a vehicle routing problem (vrp) using Google OR-Tools but with a meta-herustic different to the ones offered, which are: greedy descent, guided local search, simulated annealing, tabu search, and objective tabu search. That is what is explained in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options

From the manual (https://acrogenesis.com/or-tools/documentation/user_manual/manual/metaheuristics/metaheuristics.html) I understand that it is possible to use my own meta-heuristic. Besides, I found a person that could do it here: https://medium.com/gogovan-technology/improving-operations-with-route-optimization-e032d8bf5edc. However, I can not find examples implemented in python. Actually, I have not found any example in any language about how to use my own meta-heuristic. Although there are several examples provided in the documentation and in the repository (https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/0777e4d12ff9b45397c3aa6bbe14fc72b19bf453/examples/python/vrp.py), they focus only on using their own meta-heuristics.

As my knowledge about coding is not that high, I need some guide and ideas about how to implement it. Does anybody have done this before and can share some examples with me? or do you know where can I find some nice friendly examples? Any help or suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot directly. Not even in C++, the MetaHeuristic class is not exposed.

You should be able to derive from the SearchMonitor class in python, and reimplement the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

you must solve it on fitness(cost) function, 
notice: the input algorithm is random between max and min of solutions( example this is nodes in problem between 0 - 100).
and out put of algorithm are result of fitness function and result of how to routig and any things about best routing.
So first you must problem it for fitness function.
Suppose that, The fitness function, F, used for the genetic algorithm is a linear  combination of the. vector of waiting time, w, and travel time  (distance), d, for all passengers on the route. Therefore, the objective function for the lower  level GA is
F(w,d)= min (sum( c1*w+c2*d))
so you must select the nodes for algorithm.... 
algorithm select the 1,5,6,8,8 nodes. 
and you must calculate above formula for this nodes. in each of iteration you must calculate this formula for all population, until problem coverage to minimum result.